How are measurement functions expanded in terms of Koopman eigenfunctions in the Koopman mode decomposition?
I am trying to understand the Koopman mode decomposition as presented in Modern Koopman Theory for Dynamical Systems - Brunton et al.
Specifically, in page 16-17, the Koopman mode decomposition where a measurement function vector $\mathbf{g}(x)=[g_1(x),...g_T(x)]$ is expanded in terms of eigenfunctions $\phi_j(\mathbf{x})$:
$$g_i(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} v_{ij} \varphi_j(\mathbf{x}).
$$
In Data Driven Science and Engineering - Brunton it is also noted that the eigenfunctions $\phi_j(\mathbf{x})$ provide a basis for Hilbert space. What is the mathematical tool behind this decomposition? Why can a measurement function be expanded in such a way? What does the $v_{ij}$ quantity correspond to generally?
My aim behind this questions is to understand the difference between the Koopman modes and the Koopman eigenfunctions.
Additionally, if one could kindly suggest reading material for an introduction to the tools behind Koopman mode decomposition I would be immensly grateful.
Thank you.

What is your comfort with measure theory and functional analysis? The paper "The Multiverse of Dynamic Mode Decomposition Algorithms" by M. J. Colbrook (specifically, Section 2.1), does provide a good description.

@TroubleIsBack Thank you for the suggested reading. Unfortunately none. That's the reason I am looking for ways to approach the topic without diving into the papers from Mezic, was too dense a read for me. My background is computer science.
